# How to use ISeriealizeable attribute to serialize only relevant fields?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a class called MyBoard that looks like this

```
Public MyBoard
{
private BoardTile[,] tiles;
private bool tilesEliminated;
public int blabla {get; set; }
}
```

If i understand correctly the Serializable attribute serializes the entire class, what I'm attempting to do is to have the ability to serialize only the fields i want into XML format (other fields are irrelevant)

In my case i would like to write something that looks like this :

```
[ISerializable]
Public MyBoard
{
[SerializeMe]
private BoardTile[,] tiles;
private bool tilesEliminated;
public int blabla {get; set; }
}
```

I want to choose with some attribute what to serialize and what not, more over inside the class "BoardTile" i would like to do the same thing and choose the relevant fields also.

And then write something like this

```
main()
{
MyBoard m = new MyBoard();
//fill the tiles somehow.
m.SerializeToXml();
}
```

If i understand correctly i need to write a custom serializer by myself by inheriting ISerializable, but maybe it's possible to avoid it and letting .Net to serialize by himself automatically with some attributes that i don't know about.

By the way it's important to me that the output will be XML so i could read it.

I hope you understand my question, thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataContract` attribute and `XmlSerializer` class:

```
[DataContract]
Public MyBoard
{
    [DataMember]
    pricate BoardTile[,] tiles;

    private bool tilesEliminated;

    public int blabla {get; set; }
}
```

And serialization:

```
var board = new MyBoard();

var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyBoard));
var sw = new StringWriter();
ser.WriteObject(sw, board);
sw.Close();
var xml = sw.ToString();
```

It will serialize only members that are marked with `[DataMember]` attribute and skip the other ones.

Comment: There are two problems, first of all the WriteObject doesn't like stringwriter, so i changed it to memorystream.
But the bigger problem is that multidimensional arrays are not supported :(